# Adobe Experience Manager deployment using Maven, SVN, and Jenkins Issue

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins, deployment, aem

We are working on using Jenkins to deploy an AEM site to our development server when code gets checked in. The infrastructure is using Jenkins with Maven, JDK, and SVN configured and set up.

We have a multi-module project. The file structure is as follows:

```
/ProjectFolder/
--------------/ProjectName/
--------------/ProjectName/pom.xml
--------------/ProjectName.core/
--------------/ProjectName.core/pom.xml
--------------/ProjectName.it.launcher/
--------------/ProjectName.it.launcher/pom.xml
--------------/ProjectName.it.tests/
--------------/ProjectName.it.tests/pom.xml
--------------/ProjectName.ui.apps/
--------------/ProjectName.ui.apps/pom.xml
--------------/ProjectName.ui.content/
--------------/ProjectName.ui.content/pom.xml
```

the /ProjectName/pom.xml specifies the followin:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ProjectName</groupId>
<artifactId>ProjectName</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<description>ProjectName</description>

<modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>ui.apps</module>
    <module>ui.content</module>
    <module>it.tests</module>
    <module>it.launcher</module>
</modules>
```

With the Jenkins job set up to pull from SVN and publish using Maven, it finds the root POM (ProjectName/pom.xml) but fails with the module POM files. The following output is produced:

```
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Child module C:\Users\JenkinsSA\.jenkins\jobs\Web_PublishDevelopment\workspace\ProjectName\core of C:\Users\JenkinsSA\.jenkins\jobs\Web_PublishDevelopment\workspace\ProjectName\pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module C:\Users\JenkinsSA\.jenkins\jobs\Web_PublishDevelopment\workspace\ProjectName\ui.apps of C:\Users\JenkinsSA\.jenkins\jobs\Web_PublishDevelopment\workspace\ProjectName\pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module C:\Users\JenkinsSA\.jenkins\jobs\Web_PublishDevelopment\workspace\ProjectName\ui.content of C:\Users\JenkinsSA\.jenkins\jobs\Web_PublishDevelopment\workspace\ProjectName\pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module C:\Users\JenkinsSA\.jenkins\jobs\Web_PublishDevelopment\workspace\ProjectName\it.tests of C:\Users\JenkinsSA\.jenkins\jobs\Web_PublishDevelopment\workspace\ProjectName\pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module C:\Users\JenkinsSA\.jenkins\jobs\Web_PublishDevelopment\workspace\ProjectName\it.launcher of C:\Users\JenkinsSA\.jenkins\jobs\Web_PublishDevelopment\workspace\ProjectName\pom.xml does not exist @
```

Can anyone provide some insight in to what might be the issue with this?

Comment: can you check if all the moudles are present at - C:\Users\JenkinsSA\.jenkins\jobs\Web_PublishDevelopment\workspace\ProjectName\

Comment: The structure is ALMOST the same. instead of it being C:\Users\JenkinsSA\.jenkins\jobs\Web_PublishDevelopment\workspace\ProjectName\, it's C:\Users\JenkinsSA\.jenkins\jobs\Web_PublishDevelopment\workspace\ProjectName.core... if that makes sense (kind of hard in this comment to make it look how I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the modules in your parent pom as following-

```
<modules>
    <module>../ProjectName.core</module>
    <module>../ProjectName.ui.apps</module>
    <module>../ProjectName.ui.content</module>
    <module>../ProjectName.it.tests</module>
    <module>../ProjectName.it.launcher</module>
</modules>
```

another solution would be to keep the pom as it is and move the module folders inside the parent folder. i.e.-

```
/ProjectFolder/
--------/ProjectName/
--------------/core
--------------/it.launcher
--------------/it.tests
--------------/ui.apps
--------------/ui.content
```

Comment: I ended up copying the POM file from the /projectfolder/projectname/ to the /projectfolder/ and then added projectname to the module listing. I'll have to have a discussion with our web team to discuss how we can maintain the correct structure going forward.